# Making audio streaming with ip/port in html5

Tags: html

I'm trying to do an audio streaming using the address and port. I'm using html5 but the player does not broadcast the audio that I want. Is html5 compatible with ios and android?

```
<audio id="radio" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" >
    <source src="http://198.24.165.181:9602/;" type="audio/ogg">
    <font color="#FFFFFF">seu navegador nao suporta HTML5. Prefira o Google Chrome</font>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Chrome, the `http://198.24.165.181:9602/;` stream doesn’t play for me even in desktop Chrome. So it’s not Android-specific. The cause might be a known issue in Chrome being tracked under a bug titled **[Shoutcast streams on non-standard port would no longer play](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=669800)**.

And it seems that [WebKit may have the same issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=164530).

Incidentally, as far as iOS, given the `type="audio/ogg"` in the markup snippet in the question, it’s worth noting that WebKit—as the only browser engine available on iOS—doesn’t support the Ogg Vorbis audio format. So iOS users can’t listen to Ogg Vorbis audio content at all, because Safari and any other iOS browsers can’t play it. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=ogg-vorbis.

Edge doesn’t support Ogg Vorbis audio either. The only browser engines that support Ogg Vorbis are Gecko (Firefox’s engine) and Blink (Chrome, Opera, etc.).

---

#### Update 2017-01-21: Blink/Chrome to add special-case handling for Shoutcast

The Blink/Chrome project, after recognizing that removal of HTTP/0.9 support caused “unexpected consequences… for quite a lot of Shoutcast users” are [reverting the change for Chrome 56](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=669800#c103):

> After much discussion and looking at how many users this impacts, we plan on re-enabling HTTP/0.9 over ports other than 80 for Chrome 56.  We'll remove it again in Chrome 57, but we'll also add a hack to allow it just for responses that look to be from Shoutcast servers (Ones that start with "ICY").  So behavior should be just like it was in Chrome 54 and earlier going forward, for Shoutcast servers (Worth noting this does not quite match FireFox's current behavior).

They’re going to re-remove it in Chrome 57 but [will also add some special-case to allow HTTP/0.9 responses over ports other than 80 if the server response starts with "`ICY 200 OK`"—](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/qS63pYso4P0/FP6xymqNAwAJ)which is apparently what the Shoutcast server responds with rather than, e.g., "`HTTP/0.9 200 OK`".

Comment: My intention was to make it a webview to run the web radio on android. I see it's not possible, thank you.